# Gnuplot creates empty eps file

Tags: linux, gnuplot, ghostscript, postscript, eps

I am trying to create an EPS file using gnuplot using the following code:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced
set output 'file.eps'
plot 'mydata.dat' using 1:2
replot
quit
```

But to no avail, EPS file does not have any plot in there. I dont know what I am missing, i got ghostscript, ghostscript-fonts and psutils. EPS files is just empty white file. I have searched the web but nothing just works.

How to I generate the EPS file with plot in it?

Specs:
Fedora 21 x64_86
gnuplot-4.6 patch 5
ghostscript 9.15

Comment: Do you get any warnings? Is the data file in the same directory as the gnuplot script?

Comment: I don't, no warning of any sort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I have now solved it, It appears that there is a conflict between ghostscript and infinality so I uninstalled it

```
sudo yum remove *infinality*
```

and Viola! Things works now! :)

Comment: Quite strange because gnuplot doesn't use ghostscript at all.

Comment: even though when we deal with postscript?

Comment: Yes, gnuplot itself writes the complete raw postscript file.

Answer (score 1):

---

"conf" :

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced
set output 'file.eps'
plot 'mydata.dat' using 1:2 with linespoints
replot
quit
```

And you will need some data for the file mydata.dat, example from http://lowrank.net/gnuplot/datafile2-e.html , ref. https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=gnuplot+plot+file

```
#  X     Y1    Y2
1.0   0.0   0.1
2.0   0.0   0.1
3.0   0.0   0.1
4.0   0.1   0.2
5.0   0.6   0.4
6.0   1.0   0.9
7.0   1.2   1.7
8.0   1.3   2.4
```

`$ gnuplot conf` : OK, a nice plot, file.eps .

---

[image: file.eps]

Comment: hi! Followed this one but i don't get any nice plots, its just empty, no plot, no x and y, no box, just white. :(

Comment: No error messages ?  Is gnuplot-common installed ? `# yum install gnuplot-common` ,,, Is the 'atril' ps reader installed ?

Comment: no error, gnuplot-common is installed but still could not get that nice plot

Comment: Fedora 23 - x64_86 : `# yum install gnuplot atril` ...... No issues. Same plot as above . But : You will have to open `file.eps` with `atril` ...

Comment: I guess the eps file should be editable by inkscape, but its not, so my generated eps is an invalid file, its says: Error /invalidfont in /findfont